# Clicking on App results in "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage"

Tags: 2013, apps-development

I have made sure the environment for apps is setup properly. The App domain is created successfully and ping requests are also successful. The mandatory services are provisioned and running.
App catalog is also set up properly and I am in fact also able to add apps without any errors. Attached are the screen shots which show my setup and the errors encountered.
What am I missing?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are your alternate access mappings ?

Comment: @ArkoD THe AAM is configured with Internal Url as http://aissp2013:90, Zone:Default and Public URL for Zone: http://aissp2013:90

Answer (score 1):

Change the public url for the zone to : contosoapps.com

Comment: that did not help.